# ffmpeg poor audio(only) streaming quality? how to configure

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

ffmpeg streams audio only with bad quality.. i need better quality, lantency isn't a problem!

im making a discord bot that streams audio from my local input..

i saw the -aq short for -q:audio but changing that doesn't seem to make a diffrence.. im sure 48k samplerate should be plenty.
need stereo channel.

have no idea how to change the bitrate or the compression... maybe that might be the problem?

using ffmpeg i got it working but i found that the quality isn't perfect..
how do i get loseless audio only? or is there somthing wrong with my parameters?

```
  {
    FileName = "ffmpeg.exe",
    Arguments = $"-hide_banner -loglevel panic -f dshow -i audio=\"{Program.AUDIO_DEVICE_NAME}\" -aq 8 -ac 2 -f s16le -ar 48000 pipe:1",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true
  }
```

expected: close too or lossless quality, high lantency is fine (not more than 10 secs)

reuslt: 8/10 quality and 1.5 sec lantency.. could be better

if ffmpeg isn't the answer to my solution what else can i use?

edit: found out that the -f s16le is an audio format i tried switching to other pcm with no luck s24le gives me white noise with barely audbile audio
same as s32le? im using voice meter btw as a virtual input i suspect the low quality is because the format is only 16bit..

edit2: bitrate other than 48000 seems to dail the songs in diffrent speeds

Comment: Try the ffmpeg support in Accord.NET, this gives you plenty of configuration options

Comment: Have you tried to specify an audio codec?

Comment: yes.. but that didn't seem to affect anything.. or im using the wrong setitngs.. 
however i just found out that the quality seem to go up when streaming pc's performance is good!

Comment: Try `Arguments = $"-hide_banner -loglevel panic -f dshow -i audio=\"{Program.AUDIO_DEVICE_NAME}\" -c copy -f wav pipe:",`

Comment: thanks! logan i switch to that and it works! with good quality except the audio is pitch shifted up, bitrate didn't seem to have an effect anymore

Comment: it's fixed the argumen i used was
Arguments = $"-hide_banner -loglevel panic -f dshow -i audio=\"{Program.AUDIO_DEVICE_NAME}\" -f wav -ar 48k pipe:1"

the problem was i used 48000 instead of 48k :P